# Loading Data in a Table View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a table view in an iOS application I'm working on, and I want to load the data and start searching only when the search key on the keyboard is clicked. Presently, it loads the data when I start typing in the search field, however, since there is a lot of data, this creates a lot of lag.

I've tried looking online, but most tutorials or examples refer to loading the data immediately or when the user is typing in the search bar.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you!

### UPDATE: SOLVED

***[Thanks to Tim & channi's suggestions]***

The code below is the updated solution:

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
/* loads the file into a dictionary */
    NSString *myFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"plist"];

    dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
    recipes = [dict allKeys];

    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

    searchResults = [recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchBar.text scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

/* reloads the searchResults table view with the new data */
    [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData];
    [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
/* Sets both arrays to nil so main table view is a clean view */
    searchResults = nil;
    recipes = nil;
}
```

Comment: Code would be helpful, or more details. Are you using `UISearchBar` or `UITextField` or...? Assuming `UISearchBar` you can implement the [Delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) and then use `searchBarSearchButtonClicked:`

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to include the code to the .m file. I have tried that, but it won't actually load the data or start searching, so I'm a little confused. I'm very new to iOS programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you might call `-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope` method in `-(void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` method

let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried that as well, and it still searches while I'm typing in the search bar. I tried calling "-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString" as well and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008226-CH1-SW2) delegate method for your UISearchDisplayController. If you return `NO` from that method, your search display controller won't attempt to reload the results right away, so you can avoid lag while the user types. Later, when the user presses the Search button, you can force a reload of your results table.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I put [self.mainTableView reloadData] in the method for the search button and it's not working properly. It's still doing the search as I type in the search bar.

Comment: Did you implement the delegate as I suggested? Also, you probably want to reload the *search* table view in the method for the search button, rather than the *main* table view.

Comment: Thats a good point, I didn't think of that. I changed the delegate to return no, and I just changed the reload value to [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView reloadData] and it's still doing the same thing

Comment: So whats happening now is it's still doing the search as a type but it won't reload the table view until after I hit search

Comment: I figured it out using your suggestion and @channi's suggestion. I did as you suggested but I also called filterContentForSearchText where I reload the view.